# get single color values from argb number

Tags: c#, colors, hex

Im learning C# and the following problem im trying to solve is taking a number stored as a string and getting the a, r, g, b values.

So i want to go from

```
string s = "4280427042";
```

to

```
int a = 255;
int r = 22;
int g = 22;
int b = 22;
```

What is the best approach?

Comment: How did you get those `a, r, g, b` values from your string? I do not understand _the_ pattern.

Comment: Isn't it 0x22 instead of 22?

Answer (score 6):

You can convert the string into an unsigned 32-bit integer, and then use `BitConverter` to get the individual bytes like this:

```
string s = "4280427042";

uint argb = Convert.ToUInt32(s);

byte[] values = BitConverter.GetBytes(argb);

int a = values[3];
int r = values[2];
int g = values[1];
int b = values[0];
```

Quoting from [this MSDN reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1184xdy4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

> The order of bytes in the array returned by the GetBytes method depends on whether the computer architecture is little-endian or big-endian.

This means that you need to be careful about the order of the bytes. You can use [`BitConverter.IsLittleEndian`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.bitconverter.islittleendian.aspx) to help you with that.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`Color.FromArgb()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2zys7833%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and acces the single values like this:

```
string s = "4280427042";
Color color = Color.FromArgb((int)uint.Parse(s));

int a = color.A;
int r = color.R;
int g = color.G;
int b = color.B;
```

Note that `uint.Parse` may throw an exception if the `string` does not contain a valid `uint`. It may be better to use `uint.TryParse` and do some error handling.

*UPDATE* Thanks to the hint of Flat Eric: don't just use `int.Parse` but `uint.Parse`, because values may be greater than 2147483648 (just like the example) and so not fit into a signed int.

Comment: This does not work for the given example. I modified it a bit and it works: `Color.FromArgb((int)uint.Parse(s))`

Answer (score 1):

Look at `Color.FromArgb`. Here is the [MSDN Article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2zys7833(v=vs.110).aspx).
It returns you a `Color` which lets you access the a, r, g & b values.